# How do DataContexts flow to UserControls inside of DataTemplates?

Tags: asp.net, wpf, mvvm

I'm implementing a project with WPF-MVVM

I have a `TabControl`, where each tab represent an object `Server`.
On each tab, there is a `ListBox` which is bind on a `Application` List. 
The tab control and the `listbox` are bound on a `ServerViewModel`

The object `Application` is modelize as a `UserControl` and I want this object to be bind on another viewmodel called `ApplicationViewModel`

```
<TabControl x:Name="_tabControl"
 DataContext="{StaticResource ServerVM}"
 ItemsSource="{Binding UserServerCollection}">
  <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ApplicationCollection}">
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <view:ApplicationView />
                            </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </DataTemplate>
  </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

The problem is that the tabcontrol is well bound, the listbox has the good number of items, but the usercontrols are not well bound.

Could you help me please.
I don't know how to set the userControl datacontext

Comment: Are you trying to match your ApplicationView with a custom ViewModel for that UserControl?  Its one of the mistakes that new MVVM users do...

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to set the DataContext, it is automatically set to the templated item via inheritance and the ListBox's functionality, presumably it is an application view model from the `ApplicationCollection`.

If the `DataContext` is set inside the `ApplicationView` however, you would need to explicitly set it in the `DataTemplate` because of [precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Not sure if `DataContext="{Binding}"` would be enough but you could also try a [relative source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource.aspx) binding to the `DataContext` of the enclosing `ListBoxItem`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the object in `ApplicationCollection` be of type `ApplicationViewModel`

Your `ApplicationView` inherits it's `DataContext` from the `ListBoxItem.DataContext`, so it's default `DataContext` will be whatever object is in `ApplicationCollection`